# Two questions about the many-worlds theory

Tags: quantum-interpretations

I have a few questions about the many-worlds theory

1 The concept of time

To understand the many-world model concept, I imagined a model with three universes:

i) An orient express train in Paris, ii) the same train in Vienna and iii) the train in its final destination Istanbul.

I then imagined a jump between the states state i) to ii) to iii) (perhaps of great discomfort to the passengers) and I asked myself the more general question:

The time dimension is a valuable tool for physicists to account for the fact that things move and change, but if all movements are connected with quantum jumps to other universes, do we really need that dimension (time), bearing in mind that we should keep our toolbox as slimmed as possible?

2 Bookkeeping

The formulation of any theory must come with a claim of being able to define the theory and avoid - at least the more obvious - contradictions.

If we have a simple universe with two objects i) an atom with two quantum states, e.g. a hydrogen atom in the first state above its ground level, and another atom in its ground level. I then assume that the first atom jumps to its lowest state and emits a photon so that we now have three objects populating the universe.
If we assume that the objects are million light years away from each other, how does one construct the new universes? The old universe still prevails from the second atom’s viewpoint and the new atom’s universe still has its old companion, I presume.

If we now consider the real world I would assume that the bookkeeping of all universes would be quite a challenge. Might it not require for all its constituents, i.e. objects with quantum states, a “private” set of many-world universes?
I assume that for any quantum jump for any particle in the universe, information about the particle’s new state will expand with the speed of light to all its neighbors and make continuing changes to the bookkeeping regarding the universes to which everybody belongs.

Answer (score 2):

The many worlds interpretation (MWI) involves working out the implications of quantum mechanics and taking what it says seriously as a description of reality. One of the implications of quantum mechanics, according to the MWI, is that each system exists in multiple versions. When a system S1
measures another system S2, information about S2 is present in S1 and may spread to other systems that interact with S1. When information from S2 is copied into multiple other systems, the different results of that measurement can no longer undergo quantum interference. As a result, the different versions of that system that arise as a result of that measurement act independently of one another, as do all the records of those different versions. So as information spreads locally the different versions of all the systems that receive the information about S2 are sorted into layers and each of those layers acts approximately like the universe as described by classical physics: a collection of parallel universes. See

http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/8892/1/alyssa_volume.pdf

https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328

https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832

Since a universe is a structure that evolves over time independently of other universes, we can't just get rid of other times and say they are other universes. Time in the Everett interpretation is usually discussed in terms of a clock system being entangled with the rest of the universe and the different values of the relevant observable of the clock system correspond to different times:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04773

https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.02771

Answer (score 2):

The [Everett Interpretation](https://cqi.inf.usi.ch/qic/everett_phd.pdf) does not actually involve the creation of any extra universes. It only uses quantum superpositions. The idea is that when quantum systems for observer and observed interact, they evolve into a superposition of orthogonal (and hence non-interacting) states, each of which jointly consists of the observed system in a particular eigenstate and the observer seeing that single outcome. (See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731652) for a brief outline of how that might happen.) Back in the 1970s when Bryce DeWitt was trying to raise public awareness of Everett's proposal, he used an analogy to describe what it would look like to such a quantum observer 'from the inside' - that it would be *as if* each outcome happened in a separate world. Hence the alternative name: 'Many Worlds Interpretation'.

So your question about the bookkeeping of multiple universes is moot. There are no multiple universes. The particles evolve into superpositions of the alternative measurement outcomes purely locally, according to the standard rules of unitary quantum mechanics.

Regarding the operation of *time* across multiple 'worlds', since these 'worlds' are just superposed states in the *same* universe, time is the same for all of them. If we consider the electron passing through two slits simultaneously, the electron passing through one slit does not 'see' itself simultaneously passing through the other. (There is no mutual repulsion due to their charge, for example.) It is *as if* they were in separate universes. But for the wavefunctions to interfere as they do, the space and time they are passing through has to be the same. Both time and space have to remain aligned between the alternatives.

(This gets a lot more complicated in General Relativity, where different outcomes curve space and time in different ways, and exact alignment between alternatives is impossible. I have heard that the theory of 'superspace' was invented by John Wheeler to try to deal with this, but as Quantum Gravity is still considered an unsolved problem, I assume it didn't fully work, and nobody knows how to do it. I don't have the knowledge to say any more.)

It is not the case that "all movements are connected with quantum jumps to other universes". The classic Copenhagen Interpretation picture of quantum mechanics posits two processes: (1) smooth, reversible, unitary evolution of the unobserved wavefunction, and (2) discontinuous collapse (quantum jump) of the wavefunction to a randomly-selected eigenstate whenever it is measured. The entire point of the Everett Interpretation is to get rid of process 2. There is no collapse. There are no 'quantum jumps'. It is *an illusion* caused by the process 1 unitary evolution into a superposition of states, none of which can see any of the others. And even this illusion does not apply to the smooth process 1 changing of the state between measurements.

However, there is a way of looking at the branching Many Worlds wavefunction, described by David Deutch in his popular science book 'The Fabric of Reality', in which the universe *at different times* can be seen as alternative 'worlds' in superposition, exactly like the alternatives arising from measurement outcomes. One way to see this is to consider the start time of the universe (in the conventional picture) as a random quantum event. There is some pre-existing unstable state that spontaneously decays, like a radioactive atom, at a random time. So in the Everett picture, each possible decay time is a separate outcome, all of them existing together in superposition. At the present, we have a superposition of universes that started 13 billion years ago, universes that started only 5 billion years ago, universes that are only just starting right now, and other universes that started a hundred billion years ago. The entire history of every possible history is all happening at once, but we cannot see those other times for exactly the same reason we cannot see the other measurement outcomes. The 'observation' of the time of the big bang is a quantum measurement like any other, and so all possible answers to the question "How old is the universe?" exist simultaneously. We seem to see exactly one outcome to that measurement - we experience only one moment of time - for the same reason we see only one outcome to any *other* quantum measurement. We're actually seeing *all* of them, all at once, but the parts of outselves that see each outcome don't interact with one another. 'Now' is not singular because 'I' is not singular. We are legion.

So, you could consider the passage of time to be conceptually "connected with quantum jumps to other universes" in a sense, but it's not a very useful picture for calculation. From the point of view of a quantum observer in such a universe, it is *as if* we were moving through time, with a memory of a sequence of past events encoded in the present state, and the future yet to be decided. It is much easier and simpler to take this small local picture and treat it as if it were the whole of reality.

I don't think Deutch's speculative interpretation of different times as branches of the MWI is universally known about or accepted, even amongst MWI proponents. It's not part of Everett's thesis. But I think the suggestion is at least plausible, and the connection to your question is strong enough that it was worth mentioning.