# A question about Born's rule in the Many-worlds interpretation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-interpretations, born-rule, quantum-foundations

Can somebody explain the idea of self-locating uncertainty when there's a binary choice of eigenstates for an entanglement? I understand the idea that because you are unsure of which branch you are in, you can assign a probability for each branch based on the wave function, but if both possibilities (say the 80% and 20% possibility) are accounted for, isn't it definitionally equal, making Born's rule pretty useless?

Comment: If you can convince yourself that any quantum state is in fact "an agent who is in, or comes to be in, a particular doxastic state, where that doxastic state is difficult or impossible to characterize without using indexicals", then self-locating uncertainty may make sense in QM. Alternatively you may just consider this as one of the most ridiculous way to deal with Born's rule, and just let that notion live in its own realm, that is, pure philosophy: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-locating-beliefs/

Answer (score 3):

You're absolutely correct that in Everettian/Many Worlds interpretations you can't assign probabilities based on the number of possible branches.  This is evident for exactly the reason you point out.  But Everett realized this from the start, and was apparently clear that this wasn't how probability worked in his approach.  It's not a matter of just counting branches and saying that every branch is equally probable.

But that raises the still-unresolved formal question of where these self-locating uncertainties come from.  A nice sharp framing of this question comes from Adrian Kent in the form of the "[numbers in the sky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0624.pdf)" objection, pointing out that the correct probabilities (found in the universal wavefunction) appear to be of no more practical relevance to those agents than numbers floating in the sky.

The ideas to resolve this problem get fairly involved, but from what I understand the resolutions come in three main camps, 1) Wallace-Saunders, 2) Sebens-Carroll, and 3) Vaidman-McQueen.  For a summary of how these and other views compare and constrast, you could read [this account](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds/#ProbMWI), but it's probably worth noting that it was written by Vaidman himself.  It's fair to say that there's no consensus as to exactly how it might work, if indeed it might work at all.

Answer (score 0):

When the observer and observed interact, the combined system evolves into a superposition of mutually-orthogonal *joint* eigenstates of the combined observer-observed system in which not only the two possible observed-system eigenstates are counted, but also all the many possible states of the *observer*. (See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731652) for more detail.) If the observer is a human, with $>10^{25}$ particles involved, the result isn't a split into just *two* worlds, but *many*. 20% of those $>10^{25}$ joint states have the observed system in one eigenstate, 80% of them in the other. The vector sum of $n$ roughly equal orthogonal vectors has a length $\sqrt{n}$ times bigger; hence Born's rule.

The splitting of the observer system is usually ignored in most treatments of Many Worlds, as it can't be modelled precisely mathematically, but symmetry requires that when two systems interact, each component is thereby observing the other, and hence *both* must split into a superposition of all possible outcomes. When one of the systems is hugely complicated, like the environment, or a human, then the number of possible outcomes of the observation is vast. This sort of interaction is called *decoherence*.