Shouldn't it be possible to interact with selves in other worlds of the many-worlds interpretation (MWI)?
Under the many-worlds interpretation (MWI) of quantum mechanics, normally it's not considered possible to interact with "people" in other worlds because once the wavefunction decoheres, the wavefunctions do not interact in any way, by definition.
But I think I've thought of a way to test whether multiple "selves" truly exist in MWI, and, if it is correct, then it should be possible to interfere with oneself from another branch in a way that is visible from a third branch. I'd like to know if it is correct in theory, and if correct, whether it's practically impossible.
The idea is based on the fact that, supposing MWI is accurate, the same photon in different worlds can interfere with itself to make an interference pattern as in the double-slit experiment, despite the photon only subjectively "existing" in one universe at a time. Its wavefunction can still interfere with itself, with visible effect, as long as we do not entangle ourselves with it until the appropriate time.
This is the essence of the idea:

Put a scientist, Chauncy, in an insulated box with two chambers, each chamber of which will act as a slit in a double-slit style experiment. Let Chauncy quantum-randomly go into one of the two chambers. If MWI is true, the box will be in a superposition of states where Chauncy went into the left or the right chamber. The two "versions" of Chauncy can "interfere" with each other by adjusting the width of the slit in their respective chambers and altering the interference pattern created by the photons going through the chamber. If Chauncy went both ways, both slits should be adjusted, but if she went only one way, then only one should be adjusted, and this should be legible in the interference pattern.

If I were to boil it down, I think the crux of my proposal is: given that it's difficult to put a macroscopic object in superposition, can we use a microscopic object to create a 50/50 split in worlds for a macroscopic object, and then use the macroscopic object to influence the (superposed) wavefunction of a microscopic object in a way we can detect?
A proposal for the experimental setup is as follows:

Box a scientist (Chauncy) up in a box with two chambers. Insulate the contents of the box (and the two chambers) from the outside world so that the environment does not in any way become entangled with the contents.
Create one small aperture in one side of the box, and one on the other side of each chamber, for a total of three apertures; individual photons will enter through the first hole and exit through one of the two exit holes.
A splitter is set up at the photon entrance, so that the photon will go into one of the two chambers with equal probability, and come out the other side.
In each chamber, there is a slit of variable width, each initially sized to be the same as the other. This is basically a double-slit experiment setup.
Give the boxed scientist Chauncy a source of quantum randomness, a 1-bit quantum random number generator.
Have a scientist outside the box named Otto, with a photon gun aimed at a one-way hole into the box. (Again this is just the double-slit experiment so far, so this should be possible.)
Chauncy, scientist in the chamber, gets 1 bit of random quantum information. If the bit is 0, she goes into the left chamber, and if the bit is 1, she goes into the right chamber.
Whichever chamber Chauncy goes into, she will resize the slit to double the size it was before. This will have an effect on the interference pattern. It should be set up so that you can't tell which slit was resized from the interference pattern. (If there's some asymmetry here, we'd have to redesign the experiment to eliminate it.)
Otto fires single photons through the chamber repeatedly to get an interference pattern.

If Chauncy split, both slits should be open to the same width; but if he only went one way, one slit should be opened wider, and the other narrower. This will be detectible in the interference pattern.
So, what do you think? Can two versions of yourself interfere with each other in a way that a third party can observe it? Even if this version of the experiment won't work, is there anything to the idea that people can adjust an interference pattern?

The only way known to interact with other branches in many worlds theory is the Everett–Wheeler telephone. It is only possible if Schrödinger's equation has non linear terms.

@Mauricio but we see that photons obviously interact with themselves across branches in a double-slit experiment. That isn't visible to themselves, but it's visible to us, a "third" party. That's what I'm trying to get at.

I guess my observation is that the branches interact with each other by cancelling each other. I'm trying to design an experiment that allows a human to shape that cancelling.

@cherrypicked It is not called  an interaction of the photons in the double slit experiment. If you search on the net you will find experiments with single photons at a time still giving an interference patter, It is the quantum mechanical probability functions at work

I understand that single photons give an interference pattern. Apologies if "interaction" is the wrong word, I guess the correct word is "interference." I'm wondering if it's possible to make a human "interfere" with him/herself across universes in a way that is visible to an outside observer. I've updated my question to use terminology more correctly.

Closed as off-topic? Isn't the MWI pretty mainstream?

Agreed. This question is definitely appropriate for Phys.SE even if a few parts of it use a non-mainstream choice of words. I wouldn't say that interference effects represent "interactions between the worlds" for instance. But, whatever you call them, they should not be unique to microscopic objects.

I'm happy to clean up my question to use standard terminology, I've already altered it to correct for that in a few places.

The MWI is used in peer reviewed papers and it is just an implication of quantum theory. Also most of the question is just about the implications of quantum theory for a particular kind of experiment and it's difficult to see how that can be off topic.

The experiment wouldn't work if Chauncy is a human because he would be decohered by brreathing air in the box. David Deutsch suggested a currently unrealizable test involving a quantum AI in Section 8 of his paper "Quantum theory as a universal physical theory" https://boulderschool.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Deutsch.pdf
The rest of the content of the paper was refuted by Foster and Brown in "On a recent attempt to define the interpretation basis in the many worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00669289

@alanf that objection begs the question. We don’t know that Chauncy would be decohered. As long as Otto does not become entangled with the internals of the box, there’s a chance that everything in the box is still in superposition relative to Otto. A human shouldn’t be different than a photon.

I have not read the scenario closely, but the box will decohere even if it just radiates heat.

Only if it radiates heat into the environment that Otto is in (in other words, it could radiate heat into an insulating layer around itself; you’d just have to slow the radiation for long enough to perform the experiment). Not sure how impossible that is.

I'm not sure if the many worlds interpretation is correct. I support the pilot wave theory more. Also, I'm pretty sure these things can't have a noticeable effect on a human because it is a macroscopic body. It is possible in the microscopic world, though. But even then, if you think of this question from the perspective of the pilot wave theory, the answer intuitively comes out as "yes, they interact."

Voting to reopen. MWI is mainstream physics, and a thought experiment involving MWI is also mainstream physics.

This question raises an interesting and subtle issue about quantum theory. The answer is non-obvious and I'm not going to write it in a comment. I can be calculated entirely using the Schrodinger equation and reduced density matrices, i.e. - with mainstream physics used in thousands of papers. The question should be reopened and left open.

Full answer https://problemoriented.substack.com/p/see-the-shocking-answer-physics-stack


"If Chauncy split, both slits should be open to the same width; but if he only went one way, one slit should be opened wider and the other narrower."

No. Chauncy splits into a mutually orthogonal superposition of left chamber / right chamber, the slits split into a mutually orthogonal superposition of big-small / small-big, and the interference pattern is a mutually orthogonal superposition of patterns for differing sizes / differing sizes.

"If I were to boil it down, I think the crux of my proposal is: given that it's difficult to put a macroscopic object in superposition..."

It's easy to put a macroscopic object in superposition.
If an observer observes an object in a 50:50 superposition, the observer enters a 50:50 superposition of mutually orthogonal states seeing one outcome and states seeing the other outcome, which, because they are mutually orthogonal, cannot observe or interact with one another. So to the observer, it is as if only one outcome occurred, or as if each possible outcome occurs in a distinct world not interacting with any of the others. (There is actually only one world and one wavefunction. It just looks like many 'from the inside'.)
(See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731652 for a hand-wavy outline of the details.)

"...  and then use the macroscopic object to influence the (superposed) wavefunction of a microscopic object in a way we can detect?"

Yes. But this is just the normal interference effect predicted by all interpretations of quantum mechanics.
If you take a microscopic object and spit it into two correlated 50:50 superpositions, separate them, observe them so the two observers are in correlated superpositions, and then have the observers come back together and interact, the observers will interfere in such a way that they are jointly a superposition of observers who see up and down, or observers who see down and up. This is the EPR experiment. Each observer is in a superposition, of an observer seeing the particle spin up and an observer seeing the particle spin down. The remote observers are correlated, so when they meet up and compare notes, the component of observer $\text{A}$ who saw spin up can only interact with the component of observer $\text{B}$ who saw spin down, and vice versa. Inconsistent histories cancel out. Consistent histories are reinforced. When we sum over all possible histories, most possibilities cancel and don't happen. In the classical case, we only get one remaining. In the two-slit experiment, we get histories remaining at each peak and cancelling in each null. The correlations between remote observations occur precisely because superpositions of observer wavefunctions interfere. We can detect the interference.
The problem is that there are multiple explanations for it, depending on what standard assumptions you are willing to throw away. If you are willing to allow non-local faster-than-light backwards-in-time wavefunction collapse, you can explain it as either measurement signalling its outcome to the other through some unknown, unstated, mysterious channel that conveniently has no observable consequences to make sure the other measurement gives a correlated result, and then classical observers take the results away and find they match. This is the usual Copenhagen interpretation. Or you can assume locality, that the usual unitary evolution of the wavefunction applies, and that quantum observers are wavefunctions in mutually orthogonal superpositions that can interfere. That's the Everett interpretation or MWI. But this requires you to accept that most of the universe is unobservable - all the other components of the superposition can interfere with one another but not interact.
Whether your version of Occam's Razor objects more to gazillions of unobservable worlds or unobservable faster-than-light wavefunction collapses is a matter of taste. They make the same predictions. They are experimentally indistinguishable. One theory says the alternatives are still there but unobservable. The other says all but one of them instantaneously vanishes all across the universe for no adequately explained reason. Neither story satisfies all physicists. But since they are experimentally indistinguishable, it's not a question physics can answer or needs to answer, so most physicists ignore the question and use whatever works best for them at the time.

“so to the observer, it is as if only one outcome occurred, or as if each possible outcome occurs in a distinct world not interacting with any of the others” - the difference, I think, is that in my experiment, there is another observer who does not become directly entangled with the person in the box. Essentially this is schroedingers cat, but the cat has some ability to influence the probabilities that an outside observer (not the “inner observer”, which would be the cat) can detect.

It’s easy to put a large object in superposition, yes, but it’s not easy to get a large object (human sized) to interfere in an observable way. This is an attempt to work around that. We would have a conscious object (Chauncy) interfering with her own actions in a way that is detectable. Is that not novel?

Observers spacelike-separated from one another are effectively 'in a box' relative to the other. Each observes, without influencing the other, both in a Schrodinger's-cat superposition. When they meet up again after the experiment is like opening the box. Consciousness makes no difference - physics is not vitalist. Cancelling out worlds is Copenhagen-style collapse, not MWI.

Meeting up again after the experiment is irrelevant to the experiment though. The thing that I think consciousness adds is that it makes a more persuasive argument that the other “worlds” have a physical reality. It’s hard to argue that 50% of Chauncy’s wave doesn’t physically exist when it walked over and adjusted a slit, whereas I can rationalize that a single photon may not have had an existence in the Copenhagen “one true reality” until it hit the screen.

“The correlations between remote observations occur precisely because superpositions of observer wavefunctions interfere.” - can you explain this part and the lead up to it a bit more?

There's no problem with having conscious observers - it just doesn't change the physics. I've added a bit more explanation. Does that help?
