Can the Many-Worlds Interpretation survive without assigning multiple copies of worlds for the same observation?
In Everett's original paper, he postulates a measure $\mu (x)$ to the branches of the universal wavefunction which correspond to measurement outcomes $x$, and argues that it should be given by the born rule $\mu (a_i)=|\langle \psi |a_i\rangle|^2$. In this scheme, we simply postulate the Born rule in MWI. For example, upon measurement of spin-z on the state :
$$\sqrt {\frac 23} |\uparrow\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} |\downarrow \rangle$$
this scheme argues that, instead of only two worlds corresponding to $|\uparrow \rangle$ and $|\downarrow \rangle$, multiple worlds corresponding to each outcome are created, such that the ratio of the world counts of the two outcomes is : $\frac{\mu(\uparrow)}{\mu(\downarrow)}=2$
Now, since there are twice as many worlds for $|\uparrow\rangle$ compared to $|\downarrow\rangle$, an observer in a post-measurement world argues that there is a $\frac 23$ probability that they are in a $|\uparrow \rangle$ world.
However, many modern approaches to deriving the Born rule (e.g. by Carroll, Wallace, Deutsch, Vaidman, Zurek) try to avoid the above scheme of postulating a measure $\mu$ on the worlds.
These approaches instead want to talk about the credence that a rational agent should assign to the outcome $x$. Then, using additional assumptions about this credence, these approaches try to argue that this credence is given by the Born rule. The validity of these assumptions have been widely criticised for circularly assuming the Born rule.
But leaving the assumptions aside, I think their conclusion is just wrong. That is, if we don't postulate that more than one copy of a world can be created for a single measurement outcome,  it follows that the Born rule is an irrational strategy for betting in MWI.
Let's take 100 systems prepared in the same state :
$$\sqrt {\frac 23} |\uparrow\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} |\downarrow \rangle$$
In the Copenhagen interpretation, an experimenter would take a bet for betting in favor of $|\uparrow\rangle$, when they're offered $r:2$ odds, if $r>1$, because the expectation value is positive when $r>1$:
$$\frac 23 r - \frac 23 >0$$
In the Copenhagen interpretation, the experimenter has a unique future, and they take the bet if they calculate that the expectation value in that unique future is positive.
In the Many Worlds Interpretation, if we assume only two worlds are created upon each measurement, one for each outcome, then,  after 100 measurements, the original experimenter has $2^{100}$ different futures. A single future of the experimenter, with $k$ measurements of $up$ and $(100-k)$ measurements of $down$, makes the profit : $ka-(100-k)b$, assuming $a:b$ odds.
The money gained by the average future of the experimenter, assuming the experimenter takes $a:b$ odds, is:
$$\frac{1}{2^{100}} \sum _{r=0} ^{100}  C(100, k) (ka - (100-k))b = 50a - 50b$$
Setting this to zero gives $a=b$. Therefore, the average future of the experimenter gains $0$ dollars if they take the odds $1:1$.
If the experimenter bets according to the Born rule, which would be accepting $1:2$ odds, the average future of the experimenter loses money. Therefore, the Born rule is an objectively irrational strategy of betting in MWI.
This conclusion can be avoided by postulating that more than two worlds are created upon each measurement, such that ratios of the number of worlds, corresponding to the two outcomes, is given by the Born rule. Then Born rule becomes the optimum strategy for betting.
Thus, can Many Worlds Interpretation survive without postulating the measure $\mu$, which assigns multiple copies of worlds for the same observed outcome?

You are postulating a measure here. You are postulating a measure that assigns equal probability to each possible measurement outcome, regardless of what the original state was. Obviously this does not reproduce the Born rule

@BySymmetry I am not assigning equal probability to anything. Probabilities are a derived quantity, not a postulated quantity in MWI. I am simply showing that, if we assume only a single world exists for each outcome, then the Born rule is an irrational betting strategy in MWI

Please can you clarify what you mean with ". In the Copenhagen interpretation, an experiment would take r:2
odds, where r>1
, for betting in favor of |↑⟩
, because the expectation value is positive when r>1"?

@Ruffolo e.g. if the experimenter is offered given 2 : 1 payoffs, then they expect to gain money by betting in favor of $|\uparrow \rangle$. Hence they take the bet. Similarly, they take the bet when they're offered $r:1$ odds such that $r>1$

In my understanding, you are building some "Dutch book like" argument for Born rule and MWI with two created worlds after measurement. Why do you set the money gained by the averaged future of the experimenter to zero? It sounds an ad hoc premise for me

@Ruffolo the only purpose of setting it to zero is to derive the value of $a:b$ such that the average future gains 0. This is found to be $1:1$, since we got $a=b$. From this, we know that the average future would gain money with $a:b$ odds if $\frac{a}{b}>1$, while the average future loses money with the odds given by the Born rule. This means Born rule is the irrational betting strategy here, while it was rational in the Copenhagen interpretation

But you are averaging the possible futures, assuming all of them are equally probable? Is it based on the Principle of Ignorance? Some futures are near impossible, like to have 100 results up. If you assume all of them are equiprobable, then 1:1 will always be the case for 0 gain.

@Ruffolo it's just an average over all possible futures. it requires no notion of probability. It is calculated by the experimenter before they even perform a measurement, therefore, there are no probabilities. There is no notion of "what is the probability that a particular future will be realised", as all of the futures will be realised. The experimenter knows this. They compute the average gain over all futures to come up with a strategy, and the strategy they get contradicts what the Born rule gives

Ok I think we have different standards for what "average" means. I learned it through probability definitions. The quantity you proposed for me would be the arithmetic mean, a different notion that is only equivalent to average under equiprobability assumption.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The MWI is what you get when you assume that the equations of motion of quantum theory describe how reality works without modifications and then work out their consequences.
In unmodified quantum theory the evolution of a measurable quantity is described by an operator called an observable whose eigenvalues are the possible results of measurements of the relevant quantity. When information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed: decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
Since information is frequently copied out of any system that records a measurement result you don't get interference between records to a good approximation. As a result for any object you see in everyday life you get a bunch of different versions of the same system evolving autonomously: the quantum multiverse
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
If advocates of the MWI just postulated the Born rule probabilities for outcomes they would be no worse off than the Copenhagen interpretation but they don't have to do that. The reason is that there is more structure in the quantum multiverse than a set of parallel universes because of the complex amplitudes of states, interference, entanglement and so on. David Deutsch used that extra structure and the non-probabilitic parts of decision theory to derive the Born rule:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906015
Zurek used that extra structure too
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0308163
Deutsch and Zurek didn't postulate a measure they explained where that measure came from in the light of quantum theory.
The questioner assumes that probability is relative frequency of worlds but it isn't for reasons that have been explained by Wallace:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718
One reason the equally weighted branch rule makes no sense is that it is inconsistent. Suppose I do an experiment in which I observe an electron spin in the state:
$$
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\uparrow_z\rangle+|\downarrow_z\rangle)
$$
The equally weighted branch rule sez the probability of $|\uparrow_z\rangle$ is 50%. But suppose that if the experimenter sees that state he then measures another electron spin in the same state. Then there are three possible outcomes $|\uparrow_z\rangle|\uparrow_z\rangle,|\uparrow_z\rangle|\downarrow_z\rangle,|\downarrow_z\rangle$. So then the probability for $|\uparrow_z$ should be 2/3 by branch count. So the branch count rule is inconsistent.
I should make one more note on this quote in particular:

These approaches instead want to talk about the credence that a rational agent should assign to the outcome x.

This quote is incorrect. Wallace sometimes writes about credence. Zurek doesn't mention it. David Deutsch specifically criticises the whole idea of credence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048

Refuting those claims by correcting those
misconceptions leads to an improved theory of scientific methodology
(based on Popper’s) and testing, which allows various simplifications,
notably the elimination of everything probabilistic from the
methodology (‘Bayesian’ credences) and from fundamental physics
(stochastic processes).

I have added the emphasis in the above quote. The decision theoretic probabilities in Deutsch's view come from quantum theory and restrictions from decision theory, not from credences.
Update: The questioner seems to be confused about the difference between a payoff and odds. If I assign a value of $\alpha_a$ to the $a$th possible outcome of some measurement, then there is an observable $\hat{A}=\sum_a\alpha_a|a\rangle\langle a|$ that represents that set of rewards. The state $|\psi\rangle=\sum_a\sqrt{p_a}|a\rangle$ is what gives you information about the probabilities of outcomes. So if an observer in a specific branch gets $k_a$ outcomes with the label $a$ he gets a payoff of $\sum_ak_a\alpha_a$ in that branch. The payoff he gets in that branch is not $\sum_ak_ap_a$, which is the equivalent what the questioner states as part of his question:

A single future of the experimenter, with $k$ measurements of up and $(100−k)$ measurements of down, makes the profit : $ka−(100−k)b$, assuming $a:b$ odds.

The odds are the probabilities, i.e. - the $p_a$, not the payoffs, i.e. - the $\alpha_a$, so the expression given for the profit is wrong.

If only two worlds are created upon each measurement, and the average future of the experimenter loses money by betting according to the Born rule, then in what sense is this credence rational?

Or do these approaches secretly assume that it is possible for more than two worlds to be created upon each measurement, and then they derive their credence function as something which gives information about the actual number of worlds created?

@RyderRude I my answer I point out that David Deutsch sez there are no credences involved in the argument. So why do you keep talking about credences? And how are you planning to make money with a betting rule that, as I pointed out in my answer, explicitly requires inconsistent bets? Which bet are you going to place and why?

Sorry. I think you are not addressing my question....  If the average future loses money according to the Born rule, then why is the Born rule a good betting strategy? About the argument against branch counting, Carroll and Sebens also mention it in their paper. It proposes no inconsistency, other than that it doesn't match with the Born rule

the calculation which shows that the average future loses money does not assume branch counting to assign probabilities. no probability rule has been assumed. We simply take all the futures and compute their average gain/loss. It requires no notion of probability

@RyderRude What specific Caroll and Sebens paper are you referring to?

Carroll and Sebens 2016 paper : Self locating uncertainty and the origin of ...... Discussion: Against branch counting. Also, I would prefer if we just addressed my main question instead of side discussions

@RyderRude The equation on which you base your criticism involves a misconception, which I have pointed out in an update to my answer.

Thanks for the update. What do you mean by "If i assign the value". Are you treating these assignments as independent of the odds? The way I understand payoffs is, if I bet $100$ dollars, and the odds are 2:1, then I get 200 for winning and lose 100 for losing. Therefore, the payoffs are directly proportional to the odds, and the money I gain in a branch is directly proportional to the expression I've written in the post

I have two questions. Thanks for your patience. 1. If the values are independent degrees of freedom, then it implies we can just fine tune them to arrive at the Born rule as the best strategy 2. If the values are independently assigned by a human observer, it means Born rule isn't about expected statistics that are observed objectively, but instead about how much value a human expects to gain

Odds is an imprecise term that sometimes refers to probabilities and sometimes to payoffs, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds, so it should be avoided

Oh, in the post, I meant odds in the latter sense. So I have already used it in the sense of pay-offs offered to the experimenter. In a future with $k$ spin ups and $100-k$ spin downs, the experimenter makes $ka-(100-k)b$ dollars. Using this, I've shown that the Born rule strategy results in an average loss over all the futures. And I have concluded that, to avoid this conclusion, we have to postulate that more than two worlds can be created upon each measurement. Once we have postulated this, we can use any of Everett's, Carroll's or Deutsch's arguments to argue for the exact ratio of worlds


Thus, can Many Worlds Interpretation survive without postulating the measure $\mu$, which assigns multiple copies of worlds for the same observed outcome?

Strictly speaking, yes, depending on what's doing the measuring. If by "observed" we mean by a human, then no.
MWI is based on the idea that unitary evolution applies universally. When two isolated systems briefly interact, they jointly enter a superposition of orthogonal states, each corresponding to the observer seeing one possible outcome. But when the observer is a large and complex quantum system, it gets 'observed' too, and the joint state contains orthogonal components for each of the possible outcomes of the observation on the observer system also. So you don't just get a split into two 'worlds', one for each possible outcome of the measurement on the particle. You get a split into zillions of 'worlds', one for each combination of particle state and observer state. If the particle states have amplitudes in a ratio of $\sqrt{2}:1$, then about two thirds of those zillions will be some possible observer seeing 'up', and one third will be a possible observer outcome seeing down. Because the sub-states are mutually orthogonal, the square of their sum is the sum of their squares. (That's just the multi-dimensional version of Pythagoras' theorem.) If the components are of roughly equal magnitude (or at least, have a uniform distribution of magnitudes) then the number of components with a particular particle spin outcome is roughly proportional to the squared amplitude of that component of the particle system's wavefunction alone.
So if you consider any suitable interaction between quantum systems (microscopic as well as macroscopic) as an 'observation', then it is not necessarily the case that you get lots of worlds, and so the Born rule doesn't apply. But if we're talking about a big and complicated observer like a human, then there must necessarily be a split into lots and lots of 'worlds'.
See the discussion at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/731652 for more on how any interaction between formerly isolated quantum systems necessarily leads to a superposition of mutually orthogonal joint states of both observer system and observed system.
Edit:

...but I don't see how it can be shown that the number of branches created is proportional to the wavefunction amplitude.

It's probable that the number of branches created is infinite, depending on how far you want to take things as the amplitudes tend towards zero. I agree, I'm not being entirely rigorous here.

Also, to be clear, your approach still involves multiple worlds associated to each measurement outcome, right?

Right.

Also, all the worlds associated to a measurement outcome (say, to $|\uparrow\rangle$) are not supposed to be identical in this approach, as these worlds differ in the values of other subsequent measurements. Is this correct?

Worlds will differ because they correspond to different observer system states, while having the same observed system state. But I'm not saying you can't have identical worlds. A superposition of two identical worlds with identical amplitudes would be the same as a single world with double the amplitude. They wouldn't be mutually orthogonal, but it's not clear to me what 'interaction' between them would mean.
(I'm having to add these to the answer because I'm not allowed to comment without 50 points. That's not helpful.)

Thanks. I thought about this idea which involves subsequent observations of the $10^{23}$ atoms but I don't see how it can be shown that the number of branches created is proportional to the wavefunction amplitude. Can you give me a reference for a derivation of this?

The idea I have is that, since the Schrodinger equation is linear, we have $U ( |E\rangle ( a|\uparrow \rangle + b |\downarrow \rangle)= aU(|E\rangle |\uparrow \rangle )+ b U(|E\rangle \downarrow \rangle)$. Therefore, $a$ and $b$ are simply superposition coefficients on which the number of branches cannot depend

Also, to be clear, your approach still involves multiple worlds associated to each measurement outcome, right? But, instead of postulating it, you want to derive it as a consequence of the Schrodinger equation. Also, all the worlds associated to a measurement outcome (say, to $|\uparrow\rangle$) are not supposed to be identical in this approach, as these worlds differ in the values of other subsequent measurements. Is this correct?
